# Integrate cordova camera plugin in an app

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm having some doubts regarding how to integrate the camera plugin, how to make it work properly. Do I need to create specific buttons in the html and add the functions via JavaScript? Do I only need to declare the function?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I couldn't find anything clear on books or on the internet.

Comment: Thanks, @grizzthedj